# Can KineticJS combine images?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

Currently working on building a graphical map out of 64x64 tiles - some of these maps can exceed 50x50, so there's sometimes some hefty frame rate decrease when trying to tween it. Once these tiles are in place, they NEVER get changed/removed - so I'm wondering if there's a way to solidify a set of tiles into a single, inseparable image?

I know Kinetic provides a `node.toImage()` method, but it doesn't quite seem to fit the bill. I'm honestly not really sure what it does, but it doesn't combine images in-place in a layer. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a complete tile set out to an offscreen canvas.

Then do .toDataURL to create an image.

Then use Kinetic.Image to display that "cached" map.

Comment: Seems to be the only way to go about it. Thanks for the assist!